# How to debug(test) GcmNetworkManager?

Tags: java, android, job-scheduling

After [this](http://www.metaandroid.com/question/java-lang-securityexception-too-many-alarms-500-registered-from-pid-10790-uid-10206/) issue I decided to use an alternative and after some researches I found [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager) that has backward compatibility from 2.1 and all good, with alarms if I change the time of device the alarm is going to be triggered, question is:

How I can do this with GcmNetworkManager ?, 
I want to be able to force trigger execution of scheduled tasks.

Any ideas ?
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a debug task from the command line. Check towards the end of the [javadoc on the GcmNetworkManager class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager).

There's currently no way to trigger execution of a task that your app has scheduled. There would be security concerns to exposing a command line tool that would allow you to trigger tasks on an arbitrary package's GcmTaskService.

However, as mentioned in above documentation, you can run

```
adb shell dumpsys activity service GcmService --endpoints MyGcmTaskService
```

to get an overview of what the network manager has for your Service, whether it's ready, how many times that tag has executed since boot, etc.